# How do I get my embedded Vimeo video to resize dynamically to the width of the screen?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic, vimeo

**How do I get my embedded Vimeo video to resize dynamically to the width of the screen?**

Here's the embedded video code:

```
    <div id="vimeoVideo">
        <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/99345430?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ff9933" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

First thing I tried was to set the ***width: 100%*** and ***height: inherit*** but it doesn't size the video itself. only stretches the iframe to the width of the screen.

What I'm trying to do is make sure the video is *viewable at any screen size, not just an array of preset sizes*. I know I can grab the screen.width with Javascript, but I'm stumped as how I relate that to the iframe object. On top of that, calculating the size needed for height as well. I know the math to get the height from the width is: *H = W x 0.5625*

I really appreciate any help that comes my way.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment above but instead of using JS to set the height on every window resize (if you have a flexible width), just use CSS instead.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.26%;
 }
 
 .video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f00;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="video"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if it is portrait video?

Answer (score -2):

Answered my own Question:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var show_width = $(window).width();
        document.getElementById("vimeoVideoPlayer").style.width = (show_width) + 'px';
        document.getElementById("vimeoVideoPlayer").style.height = (show_width * 0.5625) + 'px';
    });
</script>
```

Had to attach it to the iFrame. It resizes on the page load, not dynamic as the window is resized.